# Pandas matching and replace value with regex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm triyng to use `df.Content.replace(r'^Quote.*\n+$', '', regex=True, inplace=True)` to match and replace the first part ot the string, starting with "Quote" and to end with new line, excluding all " text" and keeping the only "Another text". Nevertheless, it only removes "Quote from Atsi on 09 2 2020, 15:13", but not "text"

```
Quote from Atsi on 09 2 2020, 15:13                                                             
Text Text Text Text Text                                                                       
       Text                                                                    Text Text Text Text Text                                                                        
Text Text Text Text Text  

Another text Another text Another text Another text Another text
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the `re` module.

```py
import re
df.Content.apply(lambda x:re.sub(r"Quote.*\n+", '', x, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

### Explain

The `flags=re.DOTALL` means `make dot match newline`, which makes the `\n+` work

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked! In some cases, however, If the "Another text"  has new lines between the next  "Another text" the string gets separeted ot the second or the third occurence of new line. Is there a way to specify the first occurence of new line?

Comment: @S.Z. `r"Quote.*?\n+"`, explain: `.*?` means `non-greedy` mode, please check [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-6)